# QGIS -Listing Database tables in Qtreeview

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with python plugins for QGIS. I did python to postgres connection using  **psycopg2**.
My query to retrieve tables from database is :

```
cursor = self.con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'")

records = cursor.fetchall()
```

**record** variable has all the tables.I have one QTreeView component on my .ui form.
How to display all the tables from record variable into QTreeView .We should use QAbstractItemModel.But dont know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a top level item in your QTreeWidget (you could add it using Qt 4 Designer)? In that case you could simply use .child().setText() to add your entries:

num_layers = dlg.ui.treeWidget.topLevelItem(item).childCount()
QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(dlg.ui.treeWidget.topLevelItem(item))
dlg.ui.treeWidget.topLevelItem(item).child(num_layers).setText(0, name)

http://ghydraulic.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=ghydraulic/ghydraulic;a=blob;f=ghydraulicsplugin.py;h=19d44b2c65b1af6cd0b26c05b7e6606ed05b1965;hb=HEAD 
contains the full example.

In case you would like to add your elements as top level elements, you could use QTreeWidget::addTopLevelItem() to insert them

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#addTopLevelItem

Which Qt version do you use?